# Tiff convert to png Node js

Tags: node.js, png, tiff, imagemagick-convert

i have to convert multiple tiff to png. For example tiff which include 3 pages i should convert  to 3 png's.So i am using tiff-to-png module and i have encountered with this problem.
**Error: Command failed: convert /tiffs/one.tiff -scene 1 ./png/one/page%d.png
Invalid Parameter - /tiffs**.Bellow is my code

```
'use strict'

const tiff_to_png=require('tiff-to-png');

const options={
  logLevel:1
};

const converter=new tiff_to_png(options);

const tiffsLocation=['./tiffs/one.tiff'];
const location='./png';

converter.convertArray(tiffsLocation,location);
```

In the error context we see -/tiffs inavliiad parameter.

**tiffsLocation** is the variable which conatin my tiff file.

**location** is variable which contain path to folder where will be converted png file.

I cant understand why  i have goten this error, tiffs in this case  is the directory which contain my tiff file why i have got this error.Any ideas?

Comment: All examples for that package use absolute paths, maybe that's the problem. You can convert relative paths to absolute ones with [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st You have to install "[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)"

1. For windows, you will find .exe file. Keep it in your mind that on installation time, check "Install legacy utilities (e.g: convert)"
2. For Ubuntu:

> sudo apt install imagemagick

3. For Cent OS:

> sudo yum install ImageMagick

```
var fs=require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
//ifile: Tiff Absolute File Path
//ofile: PNG Absolute File Path (e.g: var ofile = APP_ROOT_PATH+'/data/files/png/sample.png';)
var tiff2png = spawn('convert', [ifile, ofile]);
tiff2png.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
tiff2png.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    return res.json(Utility.output('Unable to convert tiff to png','ERROR'));
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
tiff2png.on('close', function (code) {
    /**Check Your Converted file exist or not. If exist then Converted**/
    console.log('Close: ' + data);
});
tiff2png.on('error', function (code) {
    return res.json(Utility.output('ERROR: Unable to convert tiff to png','ERROR'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 libraries that do this:

- https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp
- https://github.com/lovell/sharp

In the end I went with sharp as jimp could not handle 16bit images